# matlab most efficient partial string subtract/regex

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a project where I have a huge list of email addresses (i.e. johnhahifas@example.com) and I have a list of top 5000 most common First names (i.e. john, jim etc)

I am trying to for each email address, remove any First name if it appears in the email, so that for example:

johnhahifas@example.com becomes hahifas@example.com

benTTTben@something.com becomes TTT@something.com

so far, I came up with a regex solution and a strfind solution, the regexprep is much faster; I even optimized it a little to remove the @example.com so that the operation might be faster; but it still takes forever to run.

you can download the common first names from this address (CSV file)
http://www.quietaffiliate.com/Files/CSV_Database_of_First_Names.csv

The regex code I have:

```
fileID = fopen('bademails');  
emails = textscan(fileID,'%s');
str = emails{1,1}; %//Loaded in the emails

fileID = fopen('CSV_Database_of_First_Names.csv');  
names = textscan(fileID,'%s');
Names = lower(names{1,1}); %//Loaded in the Names

K = regexprep(str,Names,''); %Regex on Names
```

Any faster solutions would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: What about `benTTTben@somethingben.comben`?

Comment: I sorted all the emails in Spark, so that all of them have valid domains, somethingben.comben would not happen in my case...

Comment: Did you profile it? Are you sure, most of the time is spent on regexprep and not on textscan?

Comment: I processed 5000 emails (5500 in the List of Names roughly) textscan and the rest of the computation took 0.5 seconds, regex took 38 seconds...

Comment: most efficient way would be not to use Matlab for this type of problem if you want it to be quick...
I personnaly would make a Trie with all the Names, and have a NULL pointer per letter of the adress. As I advance in the word, the pointer would go down the tree and eventually hit a leaf...